# Having multiple associations between two models Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, database, model, sequelize.js

I am designing a database schema for an application. It has two models.

- User
- Team

User will be associated with a team in two ways

1. As an owner

   Team.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "fk_ownerId" });

   User.hasMany(Team, { foreignKey: "fk_ownerId" });
2. As a member

   User.belongsToMany(Team, { through: 'TeamToUser' });

   Team.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'TeamToUser' });

So this way I ended up having multiple associations between two models.

Is it a good practice to make multiple associations between two models or is there any other to design these two models so that I can fetch data efficiently and with minimal piece of code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All looks good except that you didn't indicate aliases for your associations. I strongly recommend you to do it in such cases:

```js
Team.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "fk_ownerId", as: 'owner' });
User.hasMany(Team, { foreignKey: "fk_ownerId", as: 'ownedTeams' });
```

```js
User.belongsToMany(Team, { through: 'TeamToUser', as: 'teams' });

Team.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'TeamToUser', as: 'members' });
```